# Mathematic recurrence relation for calculating the complexity of the Longest Common Subsequence

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I want to calculate mathematically the recurrence relation for the LCS algorith problem. My purpose is to apply master's theorem to calculate the complexity O(2^n).

```
/* Returns length of LCS for X[0..m-1], Y[0..n-1] */
int lcs( char *X, char *Y, int m, int n )
{
   if (m == 0 || n == 0)
     return 0;
   if(X[m-1] == Y[n-1])
     return 1 + lcs(X, Y, m-1, n-1);
   else
     return max(lcs(X, Y, m, n-1), lcs(X, Y, m-1, n));
}
```

Any one can explain how to drive that recurrence relation?

Comment: In the worst case, when the strings are different, at each invocation of `lcs()` you almost double the amount of work (you call `lcs()` 2 times). That gives you exponential complexity.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze can you give the recurrence relation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence relation would be:

```
T(n,m) = T(n-1,m-1)+O(1), if (X[m-1] = Y[n-1])
         or
         T(n-1,m)+T(n,m-1)+O(1), otherwise
```

We would have to consider the worst case scenario, which would be:

```
 T(n,m) = T(n-1,m)+T(n,m-1)+O(1)
```

throughout. Which would boil down to:

```
T(n,m) <= 2^(n-1) T(0,m) + ... , if m<n (longest branch of height n)
         or
         2^(m-1) T(n,0) + ... , if n<m (longest branch of height m)
```

Here if the longest branch is of length k, we get an upper limit if assume all other branches are of height k as well.
Since both T(0,k) and T(k,0) are constants, we have

```
T(n,m) = O(2^(max(n,m)))
```

Or

```
T(n,m) = O(2^n)
```

if n and m are equal.

Comment: Can you please tell me what n & m are? Are they the left / right branches of a tree? also where do X and Y come from?

Comment: @Auston Please check the "int lcs(... )" function provided in the question for your answer.